# Which output of a BiLSTM layer should be used for classification

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch, text-classification

I am trying to implement a BiLSTM layer for a text classification problem and using PyTorch for this.

```
self.bilstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, lstm_hidden_dim//2, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
lstm_out, (ht, ct) = self.bilstm(embeddings)
```

Now, in some examples (I came across in internet) people are passing `ht` through `Linear` layer and generating output. Some people are using `lstm_out` for the same. Now I have two questions -

1. For a text classification which one should be used?
2. If I use `ht`, for `bidirectional=True` it is of the shape `(2, m, n)` - but we need `(1, m, n)` - what is the best way to convert it?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question! I'm looking at the PyTorch documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html

If i get that right, lstm_out gives you the output features of the LSTM's last layer, *for all the tokens in the sequence*. This might mean that if your LSTM has two layers and 10 words, assuming batch size of 1, you'll get an output tensor of (10,1, h) assuming uni-directionality and sequence-first orientation (also see the docs).

For the same LSTM, the size of the ht will be (2*1,1,h) because this output *only relates to the features of the last word in the sentence*, and is collated *from all the layers in the LSTM*, unlike the lstm_out which only look at the top layer.

In a nutshell, i think you want to use lstm_out for sequence classification tasks because you have features for all the tokens. Then you want to use ht for tasks that apply at sentence level like classification, as i think it is assumed that the features of the last token are the most rich in an LSTM and representative of the sentence because it contains LSTM-like linkages to all the other tokens (assuming uni-directionality, i think for bi-directionality PyTorch will slice the backward states across the layers for the last sequence too)..

if you want ht to be (1,m,n) instead of (2,m,n) , then you need only 1 layer and 1 direction. This is closely linked to the design of your architecture though, you would need to think through whether you really want to get rid of bidirectionality and keep a shallow LSTM.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the first part. For 2nd part, I found that people take concatenation of both layers also to retain bidirectional effect.